# Updating div only by specific tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script>
    $(document).on('click','a',function() {
        $.get('updateusers', function(data) {
            $('#div1').html(data);
        });
    });
</script>
```

This script works great for updating particular div, but the problem is that it can be activated by every link on the page. This script even affected by `<input type="submit">` tag. 
For example, let page contains two link

```
<a id="link1" href="#">Update the link1 div</a>
<a id="link2" href="#">Update the link2 div</a>
```

So how to change the script to be affected only by specific link, for example only by link1 ?

Comment: If it has an id, target the specific id: 'a' ==> '#link1'.  See: [jQuery Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: I can't imagine why an input would trigger the click event unless you have your inputs wrapped in anchors.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$(document).on('click','a',function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).attr('id') == 'link1') {
        $.get('updateusers', function(data) {
            $('#div1').html(data);
        });
    }
    if ($(e.target).attr('id') == 'link2') {
        $.get('updateusers', function(data) {
            $('#div1').html(data);
        });
    }
});
```

This will do a check to see if the clicked element has the ID you want.